# How to show relationship in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have two mongoose schemas 'user' and 'project' and i want to show relationship between these schemas like in mysql. How to do this?
And how can i pass user while creating a project?

> User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema();

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    fullname: {type: String},
    username : {type:String},
    password: {type:String}
});

UserSchema.methods.encryptPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
};
UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(userPassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(userPassword, this.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
}
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

> project.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema();
const User = require('./user');

const ProjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type:String},
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    publish : { type: Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating schema in Mongoose isn't like creating schema in Relational DBMS, such as MySQL, PostGreSQL.

You can use objectId, bro.

If one project just can be handled by one user, you can use something like this.

```
userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}
```

But if one project is handled by multi users

```
users: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
}]
```

Hope it will help

Answer (score 1):

### Schema Change

To create a relationship in Mongoose (MongoDB), create a property on your schema with the following properties
1. `type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`
2. `ref: "string name of the Collection this reference lives in"`

For example, if you wanted a project to contain a reference to the users inside of it, you could do the fallowing

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema();
const User = require('./user');

const ProjectSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description: {type:String},
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    publish : { type: Boolean, default: false},
    users: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', ProjectSchema);
```

### Example Opertaion

Given the above Schema, if you wanted to create a new Project and add users to it during creation, you would need to have those users' `_id` properties on hand (i.e. cached). That could mean making a prior query to the db to get all the users who will be a part of this project or having some client send you the user ids.

A much better option would be to create a project, and update its' `users` property as users are added or removed.

Here is a quick example

```
const Project = require('./models/Project.js');
let userIds = // get the user _ids some how
Project.create({ 
  title: 'A sample',
  description: 'The usual',
  publish: true,
  users: userIds
})
.then(callback);
```

Comment: how can i get that userId

Comment: @user3869304 When a new User document is saved to the database, it is automatically assigned an `_id` property. To get that users `_id`, you would need to query the database for that user, the return result being an object with all that user's properties.

Comment: @user3869304 Note that you don't need to add `_id` to your User schema. It is automatically added.